# Insert dynamically created list items in <ol> with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to come up with a script that locates a paragraph with a `class=SO-Para-Numbered-List`, takes out the `span` element turns the paragraph into an `li` and then creates an `ol` and adds all list items within it.

This is the HTML structure

```
<p class="SOPara">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
        <p class="SO-Para-Numbered-List"><span>i</span> some text </p>
        <p class="SO-Para-Numbered-List"><span>ii</span> some text</p>
        <p class="SO-Para-Numbered-List"><span>iii</span> some text </p>
        <p class="SO-Para-Numbered-List"><span>iv</span> some text</p>
        <p class="SO-Para-Numbered-List"><span>v</span> some text</p>
        <p class="SO-Para-Numbered-List"><span>vi</span>  some text</p>
        <p class="SO-Para-Numbered-List"><span>vii</span> some text </p>
<p class="SOPara">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
```

And the jquery script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //create ol
    $(".SO-Para-Numbered-List").first().before("<ol class='newList'>");
    //for each para item
    $(".SO-Para-Numbered-List").each(function(){
        //remove span
        $(this).find("span").remove();
        //save the text
        var thisContent = $(this).text();
        //replace p with li
        var newText = $(this).replaceWith("<li style='list-style-type:lower-roman;' class='SOlistItem'>"+thisContent+"</li>");
        //add items to list
        $("ol.newList").add(newText);
    });
});
```

I guess what I'm going for should look something like this

```
<ol>       
    <li style="list-style-type:lower-roman;" class="SOlistItem"> some text </li>        
    <li style="list-style-type:lower-roman;" class="SOlistItem"> some text </li>
    <li style="list-style-type:lower-roman;" class="SOlistItem"> some text </li>
    <li style="list-style-type:lower-roman;" class="SOlistItem"> some text </li>        
</ol>
```

I can't figure out how to add the `li` to the dynamically created `ol`. Any thoughts?

Is there a way of having the code do the same for each set of elements on the page i.e. create a new list with numbering starting from 1 but for each group of `<p class="SO-Para-Numbered-List"><span>i</span> some text </p>` it encounters?

I tried setting it so that is locates the previous `SOPara` which is a paragraph always preceding the ones I want to turn into list items but I'm stuck

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".SO-Para-Numbered-List").each(function(){
    if($(this).prev("p").hasClass("SOPara")){
        $(this).before("<ol class='newList'></ol>");
        $(this).siblings().nextUntil(".SOPara").each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $(this).find("span").remove();
        var listContent = $(this).text();
        var newListItem = $(this).replaceWith("<li>"+listContent+"</li>");
        });//end siblings function
    }//end if
})//end SO Para function
```

});

Comment: @RayonDabre no it will be `some text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently setting the `list-style-type` on the `li` elements, when it should be on the `ol`. Also the use of `add()` is not having the effect you're after, you should use `append()` instead.

To achieve what you require you can create a new `ol` and save it in a variable. This will then allow you to `append()` directly to it in the loop, while also removing the original `SO-Para...` elements. Try this:

```
var $ol = $('<ol class="newList">').insertBefore('.SO-Para-Numbered-List:first()');

$(".SO-Para-Numbered-List").each(function() {
    $ol.append("<li>" + $(this).find('span').remove().end().text() + "</li>");
}).remove();
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/pzo8f52n/)

Comment: Is there a way of having the code do the same for each set of elements on the page i.e. create a new list with numbering starting from 1 but for each group of <p class="SO-Para-Numbered-List"><span>i</span> some text </p> it encounters? I tried setting it so that is locates the previous SOPara which is a paragraph always preceding the ones I want to turn into list items but I'm stuck –

Answer (score 1):

You can user `insertBefore()` to get a reference to the `ul` and then append the `li`s to that

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $ul = $("<ol class='newList'>").insertBefore('.SO-Para-Numbered-List:first');

  //for each para item
  $(".SO-Para-Numbered-List").each(function() {
    $(this).find("span").remove();
    var thisContent = $(this).text();
    $('<li />', {
      'class': 'SOlistItem',
      text: thisContent
    }).css({
      'list-style-type': 'lower-roman'
    }).appendTo($ul);
  }).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="SOPara">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
<p class="SO-Para-Numbered-List"><span>i</span> some text</p>
<p class="SO-Para-Numbered-List"><span>ii</span> some text</p>
<p class="SO-Para-Numbered-List"><span>iii</span> some text</p>
<p class="SO-Para-Numbered-List"><span>iv</span> some text</p>
<p class="SO-Para-Numbered-List"><span>v</span> some text</p>
<p class="SO-Para-Numbered-List"><span>vi</span> some text</p>
<p class="SO-Para-Numbered-List"><span>vii</span> some text</p>
<p class="SOPara">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

try the append function:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("<ol class='newList'>").insertBefore('.SO-Para-Numbered-List:first');
//for each para item
$(".SO-Para-Numbered-List").each(function(){
    //remove span
    $(this).find("span").remove();
    //save the text
    var thisContent = $(this).text();
 //add items to list
    $("ol.newList").append("<li style='list-style-type:lower-roman;' class='SOlistItem'>"+thisContent+"</li>");
  
    $(this).remove();
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="SOPara">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
<p class="SO-Para-Numbered-List"><span>i</span> some text</p>
<p class="SO-Para-Numbered-List"><span>ii</span> some text</p>
<p class="SO-Para-Numbered-List"><span>iii</span> some text</p>
<p class="SO-Para-Numbered-List"><span>iv</span> some text</p>
<p class="SO-Para-Numbered-List"><span>v</span> some text</p>
<p class="SO-Para-Numbered-List"><span>vi</span> some text</p>
<p class="SO-Para-Numbered-List"><span>vii</span> some text</p>
<p class="SOPara">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".SO-Para-Numbered-List:first").before("<ol class='newList'>");
$("p.SO-Para-Numbered-List").each(function() {
    var getText = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
    $(".newList").append('<li>'+getText+'</li>');
}).remove();
```

**Working Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ydfyh19g/1/**